# FFmpeg: Update FFmpeg to the latest ( GIT ) version?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, git

I need to use the new **`xfade`** option of **`FFmpeg`** which was added about a week ago. My FFmpeg installation on the server ( Ubuntu 18.04.2 ) was about 2 months ago, so I need to update it as I'm getting the following issue:

> No such filter: xfade

So, I've tried to update FFmpeg with the following options

**Option 1**

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade ffmpeg
```

**Option 2**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Both versions say that

> ffmpeg is already the newest version (7:3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1).
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 129 not upgraded

Also, I can see some differences in the `ffmpeg -version` output from my local and from server.

[image]

As you can see, on the local it shows **`ffmpeg version git-2020-02-03-...`** but on the server it shows **`ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`**

So, for having **`xfade`** option on my server as well I need to update the FFmpeg to the latest ( GIT ) version? What else can I try?

Comment: If you want the latest git version clone the git repository and compile it yourself.

Comment: @Robert , that's exactly why I've written my question. I need to know how to do it

Comment: Google `ffmpeg compile how-to`-> https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Remove the PPA. It does not provide a current build from the git master branch.

   ```
   sudo apt remove ffmpeg
   sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
   ```
2. Get `ffmpeg`. There are two options to get `ffmpeg` from the current git master branch for Ubuntu users:

   - Follow [FFmpeg Wiki: Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) which is a step-by-step compilation guide, or
   - Download an already compiled `ffmpeg` from [johnvansickle.com](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). Make sure to download the git version as the current release branch (4.2 as of writing this answer) does not and will not include the xfade filter. Move it to `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` if you want it in your `PATH`: you may have to re-login for your shell to recognize it. Read the [FAQ](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/) for additional installation/removal info.

Compiling allows you to fully customize what you need. Downloading is quick and easy.

Comment: Thanks for the shared instructions. I've done it